# Map Firebase values correctly in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I need to get the values from Firebase. I can actually get result from the Firebase but my problem is, I cannot "map" it in my class correctly. See the properties of my class below:

```
interface Plaza {
  Lane: Lane;
}

interface Lane {
  Date: Date;
  Lane: number;
  Transaction: number;
  Manual: number;
  Unread: number;
  Advance: number;
  Percentage: string;
}
```

and this is how I try to map it:

```
reportArray: Plaza[] = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reportService.getReports().subscribe(
      list => {
        this.reportArray = list.map(item => {
          return {
          ...item.payload.val()
        };
      });
    });
```

and this is in my database:

[image]

I need to get the Node Name "Tarlac" and the subnode name "2, 11" as well.

I think it's just a matter of creating the correct classes. But I just can't figure it out.

This is what I get on debug mode:

[image]

[image]

I am new using document type db.

### Edit

This is my result now. I am more confused than before. I can actually see the Key being fetched, but where are the rest of the data? How can I get the rest of the data.

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reportService.getReports().subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
      debugger;
      this.reportArray = res.map(item => {
              return {
              ...item.payload.val()
            };
          });
    }
    
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you add some additional information about what the list looks like when you fetch it from Firebase?

Comment: @riorudo That's the thing Sir, I can't see the results. It has too many objects inside. I don't know which one to get.

Comment: You can try something like `data: item.payload.doc.data()`.

Comment: @riorudo Please see my edits. Thank you.